# Android Gradle Running Tests on Non-Debug Builds

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project with three different build types: debug, beta, and release. My test package is always created for debug builds, but QA uses the beta build and we want QA to run these tests on their vast array of devices.

I'm trying to create a testing apk for QA that is signed by the same key as the beta build. Looking through the Android-Gradle documentation, I don't see anything telling me that I can't do this, but I don't see anyway to configure this. Is there anyway I can configure which keystore is used when assembling a test apk? Or is there a way to create an unsigned test apk?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an incomplete answer to your question in that it documents what you can't do, but the `connectedAndroidTest` task, which is what runs the `androidTest` tests in your project, is hardcoded to run against the `debug` build type, and I don't see a way to point it at a different build type.

Taking the advice from [Is there a way to list task dependencies in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422054/is-there-a-way-to-list-task-dependencies-in-gradle/10424744#10424744) and examining the task dependency tree, if you run:

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

you get this in your output:

```
Verification tasks
------------------
app:check - Runs all checks. [app:lint]
app:connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for Build 'debug' on connected devices. [app:assembleDebug, app:assembleDebugTest]
app:connectedCheck - Runs all device checks on currently connected devices. [app:connectedAndroidTest]
app:deviceCheck - Runs all device checks using Device Providers and Test Servers.
```

The documentation for the `connectedAndroidTest` task claims it runs tests against `debug`, and the task dependencies (which you see with the `-all` flag) confirm that the task depends on `assembleDebug`.

Adding additional build types and flavors doesn't seem to affect the dependency on the built-in `debug` type.

It's possible that with greater Gradle-fu than mine, you could rewire the tasks to make the tests depend on a different build type, but doing this is likely to be fragile since it's bound to depend on things that aren't supported API in the Android Gradle plugin.

To answer your question most directly, though, if all you want is to run tests against a build with a different certificate, you could change the signing config on your `debug` build to use the beta certificate:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        beta {
            keyAlias 'key'
            keyPassword 'password'
            storeFile file('/path/to/beta_keystore.jks')
            storePassword 'password'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.beta
        }
        beta {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.beta
        }
    }
}
```

I tested it and I am able to run androidTest targets against debug builds that use a custom keystore in this way. However, I doubt this solves your problem, because I suspect you want to run your tests against the beta *build*, not a debug build with the beta *certificate*.

Answer (score 52):

You can now point this to a different target, I don't know when this happened, but [from the docs:](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration)

> Currently only one Build Type is tested. By default it is the debug
>   Build Type, but this can be reconfigured with:
>
> ```
> android {
>     ...
>     testBuildType "staging" 
> }
> ```

Comment: Which flavor is tested, if there are multiple flavors? Is there a testBuildFlavor setting as well as build type?

Comment: This works for me. I set `testBuildType "release"` in order to run test against the release build

Comment: @JoeBowbeer not 100% on this but I'm pretty sure *all* the flavours under a particular build type are tested sequentially

Comment: @JoeBowbeer, any idea how to specify a flavor instead of running against all flavors?

Comment: @Caleb gradle app:tasks should show the flavor-specific test tasks. Examples: connected<Variant>DebugAndroidTest and test<Variant>ReleaseUnitTest

Comment: @xialin If I use `testBuildType "release"` the Espresso classes in androidTest folder do not compile any more. It seems it can't find the Espresso dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

To add a testing source set for your build variant, follow these steps:

- In the Project window on the left, click the drop-down menu and
  select the Project view.
- Within the appropriate module folder,
  right-click the src folder and click New > Directory.
- For the directory name, enter "androidTestVariantName." For example,
  if you have a build variant called "MyFlavor" then the directory name
  shoulbe "androidTestMyFlavor." Then click OK.
- Right-click on the new directory and click New > Directory. Enter
  "java" as the directory name, and then click OK.

Now you can add tests to this new source set by following the steps above to add a new test. When you reach the Choose Destination Directory dialog, select the new variant test source set.

**The instrumented tests in `src/androidTest/` source set are shared by all build variants. When building a test APK for the "MyFlavor" variant of your app, `Gradle` combines both the `src/androidTest/` and `src/androidTestMyFlavor/` source sets.**

Another way is to put following line your in default config.

Currently only one Build Type is tested. By default it is the debug Build Type, but this can be reconfigured with:

```
android {
    ...
    testBuildType "staging"
}
```