# Android Instrumentation test does not test Release build

Tags: android, android-testing

I am currently testing my sample app using Android instrumentation test. By default, the project creates `AndroidTest` folder for me. I simply just added more  test cases into the folder.

I used to use `expresso` to trigger the UI buttons, but now I want to test use androidTest only, However, the androidTest does not seem to test my release build. I have two variants `productionRelease` and `stageDebug` in this case.

Every time I started the project by

```
./gradlew mysample:connectedCheck
```

or

```
./gradlew mysample:connectedAndroidTest
```

it tests only

```
Task :mysample:connectedStageDebugAndroidTest
```

If I want to manually start a task

```
./gradlew mysample:connectedProductionReleaeAndroidCheck
```

It complains tasks not found in mysample

```
* What went wrong:
Task 'connectedProductionReleaseAndroidTest' not found in project ':mysample'.
```

Isn't connectCheck supposed to test all the variants in my project? (`StageDebug` and `ProductionRelease`)

from `task --all`

```
mysample:connectedCheck - Runs all device checks on currently connected devices.
mysample:connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs instrumentation tests for all flavors on connected devices.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Gradle Running Tests on Non-Debug Builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923218/android-gradle-running-tests-on-non-debug-builds)

Answer (score 4):

Just tried... one can simply run `./gradlew mysample:testDebugUnitTest` and `./gradlew mysample:testReleaseUnitTest` - which runs the tests for either debug or release build. one can add the annotation `@RequiresDevice` to tests, in case eg. one requires hardware sensors.

`productionRelease` and `stageDebug` seem over-complicated (and it also not matches the rest of the naming - unless there would be `productionDebug` and `stageRelease` as well), resulting in even longer task names, would suggest to shorten...

```
buildTypes {
    debug {}
    release {}
}
```

Here when I run `./gradlew mysample:connectedAndroidTest` I rather get a

> Execution failed for task ':mysample:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

After closing Android Studio (and the ADB daemon it started), I can run the tests on hardware device. there only is a `installDebugAndroidTest` task, but no `installReleaseAndroidTest` task. `testBuildType 'release'` might run the tests against the release build - the problem is just that `androidTestImplementation` most likely is not contained then (quite useless).

Comment: Okay, so I might have misinterpreted what you've written here. So is androidTest only meant for debug builds?

Comment: One can actually change it with `testBuildType`, but for a release build likely only `UiAutomator2` could be used. `testBuildType "debug"` might be the most common and convenient.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!