# How to run "Sync Now" via the command line in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization

When I change, for example, the version of the application, I am asked to do synchronization. How to perform synchronization by command line? ./gradlew clean ./gradlew sync etc. not working.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 63
```

When I do the synchronization manually, then the commands./gradlew clean etc.. they work

Gradle 7.4.2

openjdk version "19" 2022-09-20

[I need to do this from command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IT4GC.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio how to run gradle sync manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565263/android-studio-how-to-run-gradle-sync-manually) Also see: [How to list all tasks for the master project only in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38362977/295004)

Answer (score 0):

All gradle commands, just following this steps:
[image]
And you will see thing like this (all command list):
[image]

if you just want sync your project,just click this button:
[image]

Comment: How I can run sync from command line?

Comment: There is NO "sync" command . According to my understanding, you probably taking about "./gradlew build". Or just [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565263/android-studio-how-to-run-gradle-sync-manually?noredirect=1&lq=1) may help you