# In a custom gradle plugin, how to add task depends on task which is defined in other plugin?

Tags: gradle, plugins

for example, I have a plugin:
**public class PluginA implements Plugin.**

and I will create a task *taskA*. Now I want to set: *taskA.dependsOn taskB*, but taskB is defined in PluginB.

Does it possible to do this, if can, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to know that `taskB` comes from `PluginB` to create the dependency on `taskA`: you can simply reference `taskB` by its name, as follows:

```
class PluginA implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {

        Task taskA = project.task('taskA') {
            doLast {
                println 'Executing task A from plugin A'
            }
        }
        // create dependency from taskA to taskB
        project.tasks.matching { it.name == 'taskB'}.each {
            taskA.dependsOn it
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that if your consuming project which applies `PluginA` does not apply `PluginB`, the dependency will not be created. Maybe you want/need to automatically apply `PluginB` when applying `PluginA`.

Another way would be to create this dependency only when `pluginB` is applied, using [pluginManager.withPlugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager.html#org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginManager:withPlugin(java.lang.String,%20org.gradle.api.Action)) method:

```
class PluginA implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project) {

        Task taskA = project.task('taskA') {
            doLast {
                println 'Executing task A from plugin A'
            }
        }
        project.pluginManager.withPlugin('pluginB'){                
            println "pluginB applied => adding dependency from taskA to taskB"
            project.afterEvaluate{
                taskA.dependsOn project.tasks.getByName('taskB')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I choose the second method and it works ok. And now I meet  another problem: * What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.wxy.application']
   > Task with name 'transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug' not found in project ':app'.  I set the dependsOn code in pluginA like this:taskA.dependsOn project.tasks.getByName("transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug")

Comment: maybe this task `transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug` is dynamically created so it's not yet available during configuration phase?  btw, there might be another solution:  to create the dependency directly in your `build.gradle` script like that: `afterEvaluate { tasks.getByName('taskA').dependsOn tasks.getByName('taskB') }`

Comment: void apply(Project project) {
        ......
        project.afterEvaluate {
            project.tasks.getByName("taskA").dependsOn project.tasks.getByName("taskB")
        }    I add your advice code to my custom plugin apply method, and it work fine indeed. Thank you very, very much, you are a helpful person.

Comment: you can add the `afterEvaluate` in your consuming project `build.script`, or directly in the `apply` method definition of your plugin, see my updated answer

Comment: yes, I just add it to my plugin apply method and it work fine. Perfect!

Comment: @M.Ricciuti Is there anyway to get which depending task executed `taskA` from `PluginA` ? (In this case `taskB`).

I've a requirement, where I want to know which `dependsOn` task executed my custom task. 

Is it possible?

Comment: Hi @theapache64 , I don't think this is the best place to ask new question, you should rather create new question with more details. this said: maybe you can use approach described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46931628/6899896 . BR